# Access the member of an element in a map whose value is an abstract base class in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, polymorphism

**English explanation:** I want to access the member named `foo` from the element with the key of `"bar"` from a `std::map<string, Parent *>` where `Parent` is an abstract base class.

**Code:**

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child(): var(2) {}
    int var;
};

int main() {
    map<string, Parent *> children;
    children["bar"] = new Child;
    cout << children["bar"]->var << endl; // Erroneous line
    cout << children.find("bar")->second->var << endl; // Different method, still gives the same error
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:** `‘class Parent’ has no member named ‘var’`.

I have also tried using the `boost::ptr_map` instead.

```
int main() {
    boost::ptr_map<string, Parent> children;
    string key = "bar";
    children.insert(key, new Child);
    cout << children.find(key)->second->var << endl; // Same error :(
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A bit of context: I'm implementing an [entity component system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) where `Parent`, in the real program, would be the class which all components inherit from. (Is that the right terminology?)

Comment: Virtual access is for functions, not data variables.

Answer (score 5):

You can't access `var` using a `Parent` pointer because `Parent::var` is not a thing.  Instead, try this:

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
    virtual int getVar() const = 0;
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child(): var(2) {}
    virtual int getVar() const { return var; }
private:
    int var;
};

int main() {
    map<string, Parent *> children;
    children["bar"] = new Child;
    cout << children["bar"]->getVar() << endl; // Erroneous line
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but this would be very messy and difficult because in my real program there will be many classes containing many variables that inherit `Parent`. I feel I'm missing some common c++ technique? If worst comes to worst I could just throw all of the classes into one big file, but I'm really trying to avoid that.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of making one base class for pretty much everything in a project.  This is a bad idea in C++, not least of all because it won't give you the functionality you're trying to achieve here (not without a lot of clutter as you correctly surmise).  I think your best course of action here is to rethink your design.  Perhaps even consider using a different language (some, say Ruby just to pick one example, would never have this problem).